# HTML, CSS, may a circle be a link?

Tags: html, css

I successfully "rendered" circles in HTML:

```
.articleBoxCircleInner
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius: 14px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    background-color: #707678;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

<div class="articleBoxCircleInner"></div>
<div class="articleBoxCircleInner"></div>
<div class="articleBoxCircleInner"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6e9dE/

however, they cant be links (I cant surround with A tag). How to do it?

Comment: Why can't they be links?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/SWVwu/

Comment: eeek... omg, but a DIV inside? Isnt it supposed to be a plain text? The text inside A ?

Comment: @JohnSmith It is allowed to wrap the block-level elements by `<a>` element per [HTML5 Spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#a-changes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why wrap them when you can simply make them an anchor?

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com"
    class="articleBoxCircleInner"></a>
```

[jsFiddle Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/6e9dE/1/)

If you insist, you can still wrap them (I don't see why you didn't succeed earlier).

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">
    <div class="articleBoxCircleInner"></div>
</a>
```

[jsFiddle Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/6e9dE/4/)

Comment: Was about to post. :P

Answer (score 1):

Like this: 
**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6e9dE/2/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="articleBoxCircleInner"><a href="#"></a></div>
<div class="articleBoxCircleInner"><a href="#"></a></div>
<div class="articleBoxCircleInner"><a href="#"></a></div>
```

CSS:

```
.articleBoxCircleInner
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius: 14px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    background-color: #707678;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.articleBoxCircleInner a{
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a block containing a float (which is what happens if you wrap your `<div>` in a link, the block won't expand its height to include the floated item by default. One quick fix is to add an `overflow` to the container, like this:

```
.articleBoxCircleInner
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius: 14px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    background-color: #707678;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

a {
    overflow: auto;
}

<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/6e9dE/"><div class="articleBoxCircleInner"></div></a>
<div class="articleBoxCircleInner"></div>
<div class="articleBoxCircleInner"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KquSh/